# How can i parse string and insert it in a matrix?

Tags: python, dictionary, parsing, matrix

my question is that I have two commands which are connected, first one is for example:
**Create direction DDRRLLUU** and saves it in a dictionary "key = direction and DDRRLLUU = value", (D down, R right, L left, and U up) so now I have another command which is
**Print direction 3 5** as we know direction with its value is already stored in the dictionary so now I want to print it in a matrix of *`10 * 10`* and when the user gives the matrix values e.g: (3 5) the string " DDRRLLUU " is printed in the matrixes indexes.

I did the first command but I am stuck in the matrix part of how to print the string in the given matrixes by the user. Anyone can help me? Thanks! (Sorry for the long question).
I am sorry i forgot to mention: The D, U = '|'  and R, L = '_'  hast these shapes. for example:

```
CREATE direction DDRRLLU
PRINT direction 3 5
```

(I am just entering the values(3 5) like that) and it prints the below:

```
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . _ . . . . .
. . | _ | . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
```

We can think of a shape (above) like this is printed in the terminal.

Here what i have done:

```
system_directions = {}
while(TRUE):
    command = input().split()
    if command == 'CREATE':
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    elif command[0] == 'PRINT':
        if len(command[1] in system_directions) < 2:
            print("Invalid Command!, PRINT needs atleast two arguments.")
            continue

        if command[system_directions] < 3:
            print("Invalid command")
        else:
        #this is where i am stuck! any guidance?
```

Comment: Your question is quite unclear.  What do you mean by "print it in a matrix of 10*10"?  Are you trying to show the path that was followed?  Are you just trying to print the coordinates of the cells it passed?  DDRRLLUU describes an L shape, where it overwrites itself.  How does (3 5) become that string?  Where is the starting position?  For best answers, you need to give us the entire runnable program.

Comment: I am sorry, I just mentioned the parts I forgot.

Answer (score 0):

This does what you asked, but you still have a lot of confusions.  The matrix you drew is for DRRUL.  As I said, your sample path, DDRRLLUU, goes down, goes right, then goes back left retracing its steps, then goes back up.  Also notice that, in order to show the PATH, you actually have to include spaces between each of the points.  Look at the "right" part of your example.  The spot where the _ symbol is, is actually where you would have ended up if you had gone right 1 step.

```
path = "DDRRUULL"

motion = {
    'D': (0,1),
    'R': (1,0),
    'U': (0,-1),
    'L': (-1,0)
}

draw = { 'D':'|', 'R':'-', 'U':'|', 'L':'-' }

# Make grid with spaces for motion.

grid = [list('. . . . . . . . . .')]
for row in range(9):
    grid.append( list(' '*19) )
    grid.append( list('. . . . . . . . . .'))

def walk( grid, start, path ):
    for c in path:
        delta = motion[c]
        grid[ start[1]*2 + delta[1]][start[0]*2 + delta[0]] = draw[c]
        start = (start[0]+delta[0],start[1]+delta[1])
    return grid


result = walk( grid, (2,1), path )
for row in result:
    print( ''.join(row) )
```

Output:

```
C:\tmp>python x.py  
. . . . . . . . . . 

. . .-.-. . . . . . 
    |   |
. . . . . . . . . . 
    |   |
. . .-.-. . . . . . 

. . . . . . . . . . 

. . . . . . . . . . 

. . . . . . . . . . 

. . . . . . . . . . 

. . . . . . . . . . 

. . . . . . . . . . 

C:\tmp>
```

Comment: Thank you, I understood that. I got the idea of how to implement it. It was a great help! much appreciated.